# Coexistence of light and dark

Tags: visible-light

There are two things light and dark. Is there any system where the thing is neutral, i.e we see light and dark together in same ratio. Is it possible practically/theoretically ?

Comment: Dark is not a thing in physics.

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: It's still doesn't make sense to me. It like saying: _There are two things loud and quite. Is there any system where the thing is neutral, i.e we hear loud and quiet together in same ratio. Is it possible practically/theoretically ?_

Comment: Update your readings, Aristotle is very outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Albedo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo) (Latin for whiteness) is a term for the degree to which an object reflects light.

An albedo of 1 means that the object reflects all incident light.

An albedo of 0 means than all the light is absorbed.

All real objects have albedo somewhere between 0 and 1.

If you wanted, you could think of albedo of 0.5 as neutral.

Answer (score 3):

This is not theoretically possible. The reason being is that darkness is not a "thing" in the same way light is. Since darkness is connotatively defined as a lack of visible light, one can set a theoretical maximum to the level of darkness. A place where there is absolutely no light is at the maximum level of dark. However, it does not work the other way. There is no maximum level of light. No matter how much light is in a location, more can always be added. Therefore, one can always say one of two things: either there is no minimum amount of darkness or anything that does not have the maximum amount of darkness has no darkness. Personally, I would more agree to the former than the latter.

Nevertheless, since there can be no maximum amount of light, there is no middle amount. That would be like asking what the median natural number is. Some people would argue that an infinite amount of light would then qualify as the middle light/dark ratio, but practically that is unhelpful and easily refuted.

Dark and light is not like good and evil; nothing can add darkness only remove light. It is more like empty and filled. You have an infinitely tall glass of water (the water is light). How would you define a neutral ratio between water and a lack of water?